# How to change the date format from the default type in Rails 2.0.2 using MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date, dry

I am looking for a way through which I could convert my default date format to a specific user format.

I am working on Rails 2.0.2. As we know on making use of the Scaffold command we automatically get the attributes of "id", "created_at" & "updated_at" as part of your table.

My scaffold command looks like this:-

```
script/server scaffold posts name:string title:string content:text
```

I am basically trying to implement a blog application. Now when I try to check the date when a particular blog is posted, I make use of the *helper tags* and through `<%=h post.created_at %>`in my index.html.erb file..

I am able to display the date a blog was originally created in default format which is currently like: `Tue Jan 18 13:00:05 +0530 2011` via MySql 5.1 DB . I want to change this format to Month date Year.. like in the above case it would be January 18 2011.

In this regard could you please tell me how do I go about it. I am unsure of where do I need to make what changes.

Is there a way through which I can store the data in the index.html.erb and convert it then and there to the user defined format? I am not too sure of how to go about it directly from the view..

Also, I guess this, if hard coded would be a DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) violation going against Rails principles. Could you suggest an appropriate way. Something that I can change as per a end user requirement.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Rails handles date and time conversion formats is independent of which database you are using. To override the default format, you should add an initializer to your application. I have mine at **config/initializers/time_formats.rb**. Then in that file you would define the formats you want to use throughout the app:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:just_date] = "%b %d, %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:just_time] = "%I:%M%p"
```

In order to use the new formats, you will pass the symbol to a string conversion like so:

```
<%= @post.created_at.to_s(:just_date) %>
```

Comment: I tried out your solution.. It didn't work.. I once again got back the default format date as per the one given above..

Comment: Hi, that was the issue. Thanks!! It's important that we had to restart the server to check that the changes get reflected. But I wonder how do we make out in which cases we would have to do so and otherwise not necessarily. I am curious to know the answer to it.. Interestingly.. One question leads into another..:)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `date_select_tag` in the view and pass it in the time object and it would do the magic for you. Lets say for example, your time object is created at then,

```
<%= date_select_tag, :created_at, @user.created_at %>
```

Rails would take care of converting it back and forth..

Edit: 
Also, you can convert it into date for views using `@user.created_at.to_date.strftime()` as documented here - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392

Comment: @Kanday: this would be uust what I would be looking for if didn't bother about DRY.. Your edit to your answer helped.. But I guess this would have to be hard coded in the view..for every page template.. +1 for your way to do it and the link resource..

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS

You can merge in your own (in environment.rb) for example
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :default => '%m/%d/%Y',
  :date_time12  => "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p",
  :date_time24  => "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
)

Comment: Do you mean adding the above code to my environment.rb..? I tried that .. It didn't work...

Comment: I guess this would also require a server restart..like in the case of Beerlington.. I shall try it that way and revert back in case it works this way.. Thanks for your answer..